# R import csv with proper encoding in MAC

Tags: r, csv, encoding, read.csv

I'm importing a CSV file into R with characters such as "ñ" and accents. I'm using a Mac. When importing with the default settings of read.csv()  I get strings as in
[image: Image 1].

Nonetheless, I should obtain them as in
[image: Image 2].

I've tried setting the read.csv() encoding option to the best guess of encoding as seen by guess_encoding() and to the Mac Numbers app import settings' encoding (Numbers imports the file correctly).

So far, my best fix has been to import the CSV file into Excel, change the encoding to Windows ANSI or Western ASCII and then re-import it in R. This is how I obtained [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTBQc.png) output.

Is there a way to avoid using Excel as a mid-step by importing directly in R?

Comment: Try with this:
df <-read.csv("data.csv", encoding="UTF-8", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

- In the read.csv function I used the option fileEncoding instead of encoding.
- I set fileEncoding = "CP1252"

In case someone's interested in the case, the data source was:
http://infosiap.siap.gob.mx/gobmx/datosAbiertos.php